# Xpath query to remove nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xpath

I have soap serialized part of xml file like this,
Now i want some of the objects to be remove
ex:i want image with name component

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:Image id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">
<Name id="ref-4">Component</Name>
<ImmediateState xsi:type="a2:ModifiedState" xmlns:a2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.Plugins/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">Current</ImmediateState>
</a1:Image>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:Image id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">
<Name id="ref-4">Connect</Name>
<ImmediateState xsi:type="a2:ModifiedState" xmlns:a2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.Plugins/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58">Current</ImmediateState>
</a1:Image>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So please provide me some ideas how to achieve this, I have tried in several ways I failed to achieve please help me please...
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi i am came up with another need 
as now i am able to remove nodes based on name value 
As my soap serialized xml doesnot have root nodes i have used 
 StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(filename);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<rootnode>" + Sr.ReadToEnd() + "</rootnode>");
after i remove nodes in document i can able to save with doc.save(filename);
which saves <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rootnode>........</rootnode>
I don't want this to be saved becoz as i won't be able desirialize it again...
please help me how can i achieve this 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use XSLT like this:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="spo:Image | Name | spo:Image/@id | Name/@id | Name/text()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
2. Linq2Xml:

   ```
       var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
       var elementName = XName.Get(
           "Image",
           "http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58");
       var items = 
           from x in doc.Descendants().Elements(elementName)
           select new { ImageId = x.Attribute("id").Value, NameId = x.Element("Name").Attribute("id").Value, Name = x.Element("Name").Value };
   ```
3. XPath (XDocument):

   ```
   var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

   var navigator = doc.CreateNavigator();
   var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(navigator.NameTable);
   manager.AddNamespace("spo", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58");
   var sel = navigator.Select("//descendant::spo:Image", manager);

   foreach (XPathNavigator node in sel)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
   }
   ```
4. XPath (XSLT):

   ```
   <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:for-each select="/descendant::spo:Image">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

**Update**:

```
var xml = string.Format(@"<root>{0}</root>", Resource1.String1);
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
// process document
using (var file = File.CreateText(@"file.xml"))
{
    foreach (XElement nodes in doc.Root.Elements())
    {
        file.Write(nodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: xmlns:spo="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Spo.DataModel/Spo.DataModel%2C%20Version%3D12.1.3.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3D23bd062a94e26d58"

Comment: Hi thank very much..
I want to go ahead with 2 or 3 solution but i want have query independent of namespace so can u please guide me on this 
thanks in advance..

Comment: 3) var sel = navigator.Select("//descendant::*[local-name() = 'Image']");

Comment: 2) from x in doc.Descendants().Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Image") select new { ImageId = x.Attribute("id").Value, NameId = x.Element("Name").Attribute("id").Value, Name = x.Element("Name").Value };

Comment: Hi i am came up with another need as now i am able to remove nodes based on name value As my soap serialized xml doesnot have root nodes i have used StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(filename); XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<rootnode>" + Sr.ReadToEnd() + "</rootnode>"); after i remove nodes in document i can able to save with doc.save(filename); which saves <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rootnode>........</rootnode> I don't want this to be saved becoz as i won't be able desirialize it again... please help me how can i achieve this thanks in advance

Comment: look at an Update section of my answer. This code will save all elements under **root** element of document to the file file.xml

Comment: OP should mark this answer as solved and ask another question.

Comment: Hi i am new so can u just guide me how to mark as its solved? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
IEnumerable<XElement> images = root.XPath("//Image[Name]");
```

Using this library for XPath: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

Comment: I am getting error like this for ur solution
'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'XPath' and no extension method 'XPath' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
please suggest me if I was wrong...

Comment: That is because you either didn't download the library and/or didn't add a reference to the dll in the bin/debug directory of it, or add `using XmlLib;` to your class file.  Click the Zip button near the top to get a download of the library as a zip file.

Comment: Hi i am came up with another need as now i am able to remove nodes based on name value As my soap serialized xml doesnot have root nodes i have used StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(filename); XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<rootnode>" + Sr.ReadToEnd() + "</rootnode>"); after i remove nodes in document i can able to save with doc.save(filename); which saves <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rootnode>........</rootnode> I don't want this to be saved becoz as i won't be able desirialize it again... please help me how can i achieve this thanks in advance

Comment: You should ask that as another question and mark this one solved.

Comment: Hi i am new 
so can u just guide me how  to mark as its solved?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use this XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'Image' and Name]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi i am came up with another need as now i am able to remove nodes based on name value As my soap serialized xml doesnot have root nodes i have used StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(filename); XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<rootnode>" + Sr.ReadToEnd() + "</rootnode>"); after i remove nodes in document i can able to save with doc.save(filename); which saves <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rootnode>........</rootnode> I don't want this to be saved becoz as i won't be able desirialize it again... please help me how can i achieve this thanks in advance

Comment: @user1439419: It isn't clear from your comment: "...I don't want this to be saved". What does "this" mean here? What is it that you dont want?

Comment: OP should mark this answer as solved and ask another question.

Comment: Hi i am new so can u just guide me how to mark as its solved? thanks

Comment: @user1439419: No Problem. Simply click the check-mark next to the answer.